# Transform character datetime to datetime

Tags: r, datetime, data.table

I want to create a function that transform character datetime in datetime format.

This functions contains only one parameter : the dataframe

Example of date : "1/06/2017 11:10:51"

I test something like that :

```
character_to_date <- function(df){
  for(i in which(str_detect(colnames(df),"DATE"))){
    df[,i] <- as.Date(df[,i], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  }
}
```

But I have this error :

```
Error in `[.data.table`(df, , i) : 
j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 
'i' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[,..i] or DT[,i,with=FALSE]. 
This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

How can I make good this transformation?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `data.table`, try the following:

**DATA**

```
dput(head(pp))
structure(list(DaTe = structure(c(1516213800, 1516217400, 1516221000, 
                                        1516224600, 1516228200, 1516231800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                     degc = c(9.31, 8.37, 7.5, 6.76, 6.14, 5.58), 
                     rh = c(0.5, 0.53, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59), 
                     mslp = c(1016.46, 1016.52, 1016.53, 1016.52, 1016.5, 1016.52), 
                     rain = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                     snow = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                     type = c("darksky", "darksky","darksky", "darksky", "darksky", "darksky")), 
                .Names = c("DaTe", "degc", "rh", "mslp", "rain", "snow", "type"), 
                class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

**CODE**

```
date_func <- function(z){
  todate <- function(q){
    return(as.POSIXct(q, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"))
  }
  colnum <- grep("date", tolower(colnames(z)))
  z[, (colnum) := lapply(.SD, todate), .SDcols = colnum]
  return(z)
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ww <- date_func(copy(pp))

> str(ww)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  169 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ DaTe: POSIXct, format: "2018-01-17 18:30:00" "2018-01-17 19:30:00" "2018-01-17 20:30:00" "2018-01-17 21:30:00" ...
 $ degc: num  9.31 8.37 7.5 6.76 6.14 5.58 4.87 4.07 3.86 5.14 ...
 $ rh  : num  0.5 0.53 0.56 0.57 0.58 0.59 0.6 0.61 0.6 0.53 ...
 $ mslp: num  1016 1017 1017 1017 1016 ...
 $ rain: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ snow: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ type: chr  "darksky" "darksky" "darksky" "darksky" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Whereas for `pp`, we had:

```
> str(pp)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  169 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ DaTe: chr  "2018-01-17 18:30:00" "2018-01-17 19:30:00" "2018-01-17 20:30:00" "2018-01-17 21:30:00" ...
 $ degc: num  9.31 8.37 7.5 6.76 6.14 5.58 4.87 4.07 3.86 5.14 ...
 $ rh  : num  0.5 0.53 0.56 0.57 0.58 0.59 0.6 0.61 0.6 0.53 ...
 $ mslp: num  1016 1017 1017 1017 1016 ...
 $ rain: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ snow: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ type: chr  "darksky" "darksky" "darksky" "darksky" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Bear in mind the following:

1. I used `tolower` since the column names may have different cases.
2. I used `copy(pp)` in the function call instead of only `pp`. This is because `data.table` updates by reference. Not using this would do the changes on `pp` directly - which is okay if that's what you want. In that case, `ww` and `pp` would both refer to `pp` which has been modified.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

the function `mdy_hms` in the `lubridate` package will already do this for you and if you combine that with `mutate_at` in the `dplyr` package then you can do it for any column that contains the string `DATE`.

```
df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains("DATE")), .funs = lubridate::mdy_hms)
```

if you want this to be a function to use multiple times you can do this:

```
my_func <- function(data){
  df %>% 
    mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains("DATE")), .funs = lubridate::mdy_hms)
}
```

then run:

```
my_func(df)
```